# Speeding up Terraform artifact transfer in CI/CD

Tags: terraform, github-actions

We are using GitHub Actions and the general flow is that,

- On a pull request, `terraform plan -out plan` is executed in GitHub Actions on a feature branch
- On pull request merge, `terraform apply` on the above plan is executed in GitHub actions on the main develop branch

However, the problem with this approach is that we are using artifacts to upload/download the plan which take 20+ mins to upload/download due to our large repo.

`plan.yaml`

```
- name: "Upload Plan"
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
with:
  name: artifact
  if-no-files-found: ignore
  path: |
    ${{ steps.terraform.outputs.upload-base-path }}
    !.git
    !${{ inputs.environment-name }}/.terraform/providers
```

`apply.yaml`

```
- name: "Download Artifact"
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: artifact
```

Is there a way to speed this process up while still maintaining the general flow?

Comment: Are you performing some kind of compression before uploading artifact? That would reduce some upload and download time.

Comment: To avoid this upload/download completely, you have to combine both jobs into one. That should be much faster.